# How can I extract this relay?

Tags: relay

How do you take out a relay from the box it's inserted in?

Notice the pink one in the picture. It has a gray rectangle, and on the other side it has a horizontal one. I am sure you need to do something with those to take it out, but I just can't figure out what :/

I tried pushing them in all directions, inserting a screwdriver in-between... but nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pull the relay out from the terminal block.

There are 4 or 5 terminals which grip tightly so that the current does not cause any heating damage.